# Trying to update a small analysis, does anyone have a source on current median transaction sizes?

Tags: transaction-data, bulletproofs

Doing this little shitpost: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/9s5n51/monero_selfish_mining_strategy_when_you_need_to/, need to update because it's currently using RingCT figures

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, there have been `7331` blocks containing `40988` non-coinbase transactions since the Bulletproof fork height at `1685555`.

```
Lowest transaction size:              1869 bytes
5th percentile transaction size:      1875 bytes
Median transaction size:              2330 bytes
95th percentile transaction size:     6063 bytes
Highest transaction size:           121208 bytes
```

For comparison, here are the stats for the 1000 blocks directly preceeding the Bulletproof fork:

`1000` blocks containing `5260` non-coinbase transactions:

```
Lowest transaction size:              6954 bytes
5th percentile transaction size:     13191 bytes
Median transaction size:             13786 bytes
95th percentile transaction size:    39149 bytes
Highest transaction size:           260489 bytes
```